# GTM dataLayer setting UUID only works after event / pageview is triggered

Tags: google-analytics, google-analytics-api

I'm setting

dataLayer.push({userId: 'someId'}) when User Login to my platform, and I have User-ID feature enabled,

Inside my Views, I have View that's only showing Users with set userId, I notice that user won't show up until I either trigger pageView or some custom event after setting that userId

Is there a workaround for it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can send the pageview after you have obtained the value of the userId, for example to DOM ready.

Comment: Yes, I believe I'm goona do that! Thanks!